# Regular expression in C not working as I expected

Tags: c, regex, string, match

I tested this regular expression on a regex checker website and it came back as a match, but when I am trying to implement the logic in c I am not getting a match. Why is Ba-9 not matching with the regex even though it should be matching.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <regex.h>
int isReserved(char* ptr, char* reserved){ //0 is false and 1 is true for bool
    int i = 0;
    while (ptr[i] != '\0') {
        if (ptr[i] == reserved[i]) {
            i++;
        } else
            return 0;
    }
    if(reserved[i] != '\0')
        return 0;
    return 1;
}

int isTAGS(char* ptr){
    char* arr = "TAGS";
    return isReserved(ptr, arr);
}
int isBEGIN(char* ptr){
    char* arr = "BEGIN";
    return isReserved(ptr, arr);
}

int isSEQUENCE(char* ptr){
    char* arr = "SEQUENCE";
    return isReserved(ptr, arr);
}
int isINTEGER(char* ptr){
    char* arr = "INTEGER";
    return isReserved(ptr, arr);
}
int isDATE(char* ptr){
    char* arr = "DATE";
    return isReserved(ptr, arr);
}
int isEND(char* ptr){
    char* arr = "END";
    return isReserved(ptr, arr);
}


int main() {
    regex_t regex;
    int value;
//    regcomp(&regex,"^[A-Z](([0-9a-zA-Z]*-[0-9a-zA-Z]*)*+[0-9a-zA-Z]*)*",0);
    regcomp(&regex,"^[A-Z](([0-9a-zA-Z]*-[0-9a-zA-Z]*)*[0-9a-zA-Z]*)*",0);
    value = regexec(&regex, "Ba-9", 0, NULL, 0);
    printf("%i", value); //0 is a regex match
    return 0;
}


//    char* string = "END";
//    printf("%i",isEND(string));
```

Comment: Please update your question to show the entire source file, with all required `#include` directives.

Comment: @KeithThompson Okay, I have pasted my whole main file.

Comment: Please provide sample input string and your expected output. The regex in C supports `ERE`, not `PCRE`. If you expect a `possesive quantifier` such as `.*+`, it is out of the capability of regex in C.

Comment: @tshiono so what I am trying to do is impossible in c? An example input is: Ba-9 and it would output 0.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. I'm afraid the string `Ba-9` is too simple to understand what you expect. Could you please provide several sample strings with the information which should match and which should not. If you can describe the expected pattern `in English`, it will also be a good help.

Comment: Because your cflags argument to `regcomp()` is 0, it's using Basic RE syntax where unescaped parentheses are literals

Comment: You also need to check the return value of `regcomp()` to see if it succeeded or not before using `regex`.

Comment: @tshiono an positive number (one or more) of letters, digits, and hyphens. The first character must be an upper-case letter. A hyphen cannot be the last character. A hyphen cannot be immediately followed by another hyphen.

Comment: Would you please try `regcomp(&regex,"^[A-Z](-?[0-9a-zA-Z]+)*$",REG_EXTENDED);`

Comment: @tshiono yes that accepted Ba-9, thought it also accepts things like Ba but the string needs to have one letter, one number, and one hyphen.

Comment: Most of the source you posted is unused, You define 6 functions (names starting with `is`) that you never call.

Comment: @tshiono C itself does not support regular expressions. The `<regex.h>` header is defined by POSIX, a secondary standard.

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <regex.h>

int main() {
    regex_t regex;
    int value;
    char str[BUFSIZ];
    FILE *fp;
    if (NULL == (fp = fopen("test.txt", "r"))) {                        // read a test file "test.txt"
        perror("test.txt");
        exit(1);
    }
    regcomp(&regex, "^[A-Z]([0-9a-zA-Z]*-[0-9a-zA-Z]+)*([0-9a-zA-Z]*-[0-9a-zA-Z]*[0-9]+[0-9a-zA-Z]*|[0-9a-zA-Z]*[0-9]+[0-9a-zA-Z]*-[0-9a-zA-Z]+)+(-[0-9a-zA-Z])*$", REG_EXTENDED);
    while (NULL != (fgets(str, BUFSIZ, fp))) {                          // loop over each line
        str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = 0;                                    // remove trailing newline character
        value = regexec(&regex, str, 0, NULL, 0);                       // test the regex
        printf("%-10s: %s\n", str, value ? "no match" : "match");       // show the result
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

`test.txt`:

```
Ba-9
Ba
B9-
B-9
B--9
B9--
B-9-
B-9-9
B-9-a
B01-2
B1a-2
B1-A
B-A
BA1-2
BA1-a
BA-2
B-A-2
B-2
B-2a
```

Result of execution:

```
Ba-9      : match
Ba        : no match
B9-       : no match
B-9       : match
B--9      : no match
B9--      : no match
B-9-      : no match
B-9-9     : match
B-9-a     : match
B01-2     : match
B1a-2     : match
B1-A      : match
B-A       : no match
BA1-2     : match
BA1-a     : match
BA-2      : match
B-A-2     : match
B-2       : match
B-2a      : match
```

**[Explanation]**

Let me simplify `[0-9a-zA-Z]` as `\w` and `[0-9]` as `\d` just for the
*explanation purpose*, although C regex *does not* accept these shorthands.
Then the regex

```
^[A-Z]([0-9a-zA-Z]*-[0-9a-zA-Z]+)*([0-9a-zA-Z]*-[0-9a-zA-Z]*[0-9]+[0-9a-zA-Z]*|[0-9a-zA-Z]*[0-9]+[0-9a-zA-Z]*-[0-9a-zA-Z]+)+(-[0-9a-zA-Z])*$
```

can be shortened as:

```
^[A-Z](\w*-\w+)*(\w*-\w*\d+\w*|\w*\d+\w*-\w+)+(-\w)*$
```

which will be more legible.

- The most essential part is `(\w*-\w*\d+\w*|\w*\d+\w*-\w+)+` which is
  an alternation of either `\w*-\w*\d+\w*` or `\w*\d+\w*-\w+`. This part
  assures the string contains at least one digit and at least one hyphen,
  as well as one letter due to the regex `[A-Z]` at the beginning.
- The intermedial expressions `(\w*-\w+)*` and `(-\w)*` allow extra
  substring composed of alphanumeric characters and a hyphen.
- Each subexpression does not allow to end with a hypen, preventing
  from matching two or more sequential hyphens and/or a hyphen at the
  end of the string.